# there is a difference between these two fors?

Tags: c++

the usual :

```
 for(int i=0 ; i<252 ; i++) grid_color[i]=0.4;
```

unusal :

```
for(int i=0 ; i<252 ; grid_color[i++]=0.4) ;
```

there is any difference between both of them ? actualy I asking to myself if the unusal is faster than the usual

Comment: the unusual works, but you can surely avoid it lest the maintainers of your code bang their head on the wall. Code needs to be readable. Also, you shouldn't worry if one is faster than the other: this is not an optimisation, its obfuscation!

Comment: @Thrustmaster turn your comment to answer and the pt will be your

Comment: The second is a maintenance nightmare! It took me a couple of minutes to check if it has an off-by-one error.

Comment: Its okay, you can accept @Petr's answer below. For non-academic purposes, the "unusual" is okay; actually you can obfuscate it even more :P. For a real code in production, **never** use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no significant difference between the two. Second one is combining loop increment with loop body. There should also be no difference in execution speed.

Comment: (And it makes me want to vomit a bit.)

Answer (score 0):

style is the main difference (and consequences of style, such as maintainability)

I hope you will find that the 2nd gets poor votes in this regard.

Re: your sub-question, there should be no speed difference.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference.  Choose the first over the second.  In fact, to avoid making a mistake when adding additional instructions to the for-loop body, consider always using braces.

```
for(int i=0 ; i<252 ; i++){
    grid_color[i]=0.4;
}
```

You of course don't have to, but it's worth considering from a maintenance point of view.

Since you seem concerned about efficiency, try making a habit of only using the post-increment operator over the pre-increment operator when you absolutely need to(when the order of operations requires it to get the correct result).  In the event of a basic for-loop like this, you should really be using the pre-increment operator.

```
for(int i=0 ; i<252 ; ++i){
    grid_color[i]=0.4;
}
```

For fundamental types such as int, it really doesn't matter, but you may want to get in the habit of using the pre-increment over the post increment, because the post increment has to create a copy, perform the increment, and return the copy.  The pre-increment simply increments and returns the value.  This choice may become an efficiency concern on non basic types; iterators for example.

Lastly, if you are using the C++11 standard, consider using the brace initializers which have been designed to work on all types(if you make your own type, you will have to implement that functionality).

```
for(int i{0}; i<252 ; ++i){
    grid_color[i]=0.4;
}
```

Fun fact:  If you initialize an int without a value, it will be zero.

```
for(int i{}; i<252 ; ++i){
    grid_color[i]=0.4;
}
```

I would still put the zero in there though.

**NEVER DO THIS:**

```
for(int i; i<252 ; ++i){
    grid_color[i]=0.4;
}
```

**The variable i is undefined.**